# Spring Framework.... wat is difference between form:errors path and form:lable path...?

Tags: spring-mvc

i AM NEW TO Spring Framework . Can any body explain me difference  between form:label path and form:errors path and Spring:message

I am confuse ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

form:label renders an html label element

form:errors render an span element showing an error message after validating a form

spring:message is the element used to show internationalized messages

Comment: can u please explain me below code :                         <form:label path="code"><spring:message code="label.loccode"/></form:label> if form:label path renders an html element then wat is the use of placing sping:message . is this useful to bind label with that path(Position)..??? pls reply...>>!!!

Comment: `<spring:message code="label.loccode" />`is going to show a message according to the configured locale, so that will be the value of the form:label element